# installed rails 4 but saying its not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

i had an issue before but now i sort of ran into another issue and was wondering if anybody had any clue what is the solution to it. it says rails is installed in my gem list but when i try to run it i get `Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

when i do gem list command heres my results

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
actionmailer (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
actionpack (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
activemodel (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
activerecord (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activeresource (3.2.14)
activesupport (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
arel (4.0.0, 3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.14)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.5)
io-console (0.4.2)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.7.7)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.25)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.7.9)
mysql2 (0.3.13)
polyglot (0.3.3)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
railties (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0, 3.12.2)
rubygems-update (2.0.7)
sprockets (2.10.0, 2.2.2)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.37)`
```

and heres my gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/Anthony/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

any thoughts?? when i do which rails i get `/usr/bin/rails` also

heres my $PATH `/Users/Anthony/.rbenv/shims:/Users/Anthony/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

```
ls -la output

`Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:~ Anthony$ ls -al /Users/Anthony/.rbenv/shims
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 Anthony  staff   68 Sep 17 00:43 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 Anthony  staff  136 Sep  2 22:33 ..
Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:~ Anthony$`
```

gem install rails output

```
Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:~ Anthony$ gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for rails-4.0.0
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/belongs_to.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xF4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/book_icon.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x91" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/bullet.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xF5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/chapters_icon.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xF5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/check_bullet.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xF4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/credits_pic_blank.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/csrf.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/edge_badge.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x9E" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/favicon.ico, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/feature_tile.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/footer_tile.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/fxn.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/challenge.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/confirm_dialog.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/forbidden_attributes_for_new_post.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/form_with_errors.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/index_action_with_edit_link.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/new_post.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/post_with_comments.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/rails_welcome.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/routing_error_no_controller.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/routing_error_no_route_matches.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/show_action_for_posts.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/template_is_missing_posts_new.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/undefined_method_post_path.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/unknown_action_create_for_posts.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/unknown_action_new_for_posts.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/grey_bullet.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/habtm.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/has_many.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/has_many_through.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/has_one.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/has_one_through.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/header_backdrop.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/header_tile.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_html_safe.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_localized_pirate.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_translated_en.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_translated_pirate.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_translation_missing.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_untranslated.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/1.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/10.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/11.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/12.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/13.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/14.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/15.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/2.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/3.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/4.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/5.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/6.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/7.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/8.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/9.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/caution.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/example.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/home.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/important.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/next.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/note.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/prev.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/tip.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/up.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/warning.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/jaimeiniesta.jpg, skipping
unable to convert "\xF5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/nav_arrow.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/oscardelben.jpg, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/polymorphic.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/radar.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/rails4_features.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/rails_guides_kindle_cover.jpg, skipping
unable to convert "\xEC" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/rails_guides_logo.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x8C" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/rails_logo_remix.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/session_fixation.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_grey.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_info.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_note.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_red.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_yellow.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_yellow.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/vijaydev.jpg, skipping
1 gem installed
```

heres my bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

#eval "$(rbenv init -)"

export RBENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.rbenv"
if [ -d "${RBENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

which rbenv output

```
Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:~ Anthony$ rbenv version
system (set by /Users/Anthony/.rbenv/version)
```

**EDIT**

output

```
Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:~ Anthony$ echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" >> ~/.gemrc
Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:~ Anthony$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.0/README.md
Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:~ Anthony$ gem list | grep rails
rails (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:~ Anthony$ rbenv rehash
Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:~ Anthony$
```

Comment: It sounds like your PATH is messed up.  Your homebrew directories should come before /usr/bin.   Read this: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#understanding-path. In the future, post all commands Don't say , 'My gem list says....' Always post the exact command you issued, including the directory in which it was issued, i.e. copy and paste everything.

Comment: Post the results of `$ echo $PATH`

Comment: Generally speaking installing gems using `sudo` causes problems.  Are you unable to install using `gem install rails`?

Comment: try `rbenv rehash`? I don't think it is installed to the right Ruby though. If you are installing using `rbenv` versions of ruby it should be installed to `/Users/username/.rbenv/shims/rails`.

Comment: Did you install anything (ruby, rbenv, rails, etc.) using sudo?  Post the output of `$ls -al /Users/Anthony/.rbenv/shims`

Comment: @muttonlamb i used gem install rails to download rails.it downloaded but when i try to use rails it says it not installed

Comment: nah i dont think i did install anything using sudo that i can remember @7stud

Comment: @j03w i tried `rbenv rehash` nothing changed. and i went to the `/Users/username/.rbenv/shims` but there was no rails in there

Comment: @muttonlamb i just understood your question, sorry but i tried gem install rails and posted the results in the original post.

Comment: Post your .bash_profile file.  Also, post the steps or tutorial you used to install rbenv.

Comment: i posted my .bash_profile, as for the steps to install rbenv all i did was `brew install rbenv` then `brew install rbenv`then i went into the bash profile and did eval `"$(rbenv init -)"` @7stud

Comment: the reason why there is that if statement is because i had someone tell me that i should try that and comment out the `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` not sure if that affects anything @7stud

Comment: Post the output of `$ which rvm`

Comment: i did `rvm implode` before i posted my original post and then deleted the necessary that it told me too and i was able to download rails before i wasnt even able to download it. it always said fail but when i did `which rvm` nothing happen @7stud

Comment: what does it say when you run `rbenv versions`

Comment: sorry for a late response but i posted the output in the original post @j03w

Comment: Try: (0) Use one of rvm
 or rbenv, not both. (1) `echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" >> ~/.gemrc` (2) do not use sudo (3) `gem install rails` (4) check presence `gem list | grep rails` (5) `rbenv rehas` (6) log out of terminal and then log in again

Comment: Have you install `rb-install`? If you have then run `rbenv install YOUR RUBY VERSION`. Double tab should give you the list of versions available. Then `rbenv global YOUR RUBY VERSION`. Then try installing `rails` again.

Comment: im going to try both of those suggestions now but i have a question. do you think if i was to go into recovery mode erase the drive and then go into disk utilities and reinstall mac osx would that make everything go back to factory setting and fix the terminal?? @Zabba

Comment: @j03w check my previous comment please.

Comment: @zabba check original post for the output

Comment: yeah so you install `ruby` using `homebrew` not `rbenv` so two choices: remove `rbenv` or install another ruby version using `rbenv` (via `ruby-build` or manual). You can also manually moving the installed ruby to `~/.rbenv` folder but I can't guarantee that everything will work.

Comment: how would i remove rbenv? @j03w

Comment: ok big update. i reset my macbook pro back to factory setting and everything is back to how it was when i first took my mac out the box. im gonna reinstall everything and hope not to mess it up this time. thank you all for your assistance. wish we could of solved it but i need to keep moving foward in my learning process. thank you